# Widget data from Fragment to Activity

Tags: android, kotlin

An Activity opens fragments A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,.... in a PageView2, which obviously slides back and forth through the fragments, all the fragments are using binding view layouts they only know about their own layout not each others, the Activity only knows it's own layout binding, so when a user changes widgets within the fragments how does that data get sent back to the Activity, in a collective way that one place can access all changes made to fragments A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,.... so that the input can be saved.

The way I'd like it to work is;

1. User Clicks Edit
2. Makes alterations within the fragments
3. Chooses Apply or Cancel changes.

Well it works to a point, the problem is if the Fragments haven't been initialized, you get an instant crash, I presume I'm doing this wrong.

```
class mySharedViewModel : ViewModel() {

    lateinit var udetails : FragmentEdcardsDetailsBinding
    lateinit var uanswers : FragmentEdcardsAnswersBinding
    lateinit var umath : FragmentEdcardsMathBinding
    lateinit var uanimimage : FragmentEdcardsMediaAnimimageBinding
    lateinit var ufullscreen : FragmentEdcardsMediaFullscreenimageBinding
    lateinit var uvideo : FragmentEdcardsMediaVideoBinding
    lateinit var uaudio : FragmentEdcardsMediaAudioBinding

    fun cardapply() {

        mytools.debug("${udetails}" )
        mytools.debug("${uanswers}" )
    }

}
```

**Edit 2**

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    u = FragmentEdcardsDetailsBinding.bind(view)
    model.udetails= u
    model.udetailsinit = true
```

Created a workaround, my gut is still telling me this is way wrong! idea being when apply is press it checks if model.udetailinit is true, because testing an uninitialized udetail just results in crash.

Comment: Use view model. [https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Comment: I presume your directing me to https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing as it appears to be something that stands out.

Comment: Yes. Just in case if you are not familiar with ViewModel, you should read from the beginning. Otherwise, you can just read that part.

Answer (score 1):

This should be done using a [shared ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing), you should create a `ViewModel` object in your `Activity` and then access this `ViewModel` using Activity scope in your fragments.

Define a `ViewModel` as

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
   val action: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
}
```

In `Activity` create object of this `ViewModel`

```
class SomeActivity: AppCompatActivity(){
    // create ViewModel 
    val model: MyViewModel by viewModels()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        model.action.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<String> { action->
            // Do something with action
        })
    }
}
```

And in your Fragments access the `ViewModel` from `Activity` Scope

```
class SomeFragment: Fragment() {
    private val model: MyViewModel by activityViewModels()
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        
        // Change value of action and notify Activity
        model.action.value = "SomeAction"
    }
}
```

Comment: nice, thank you. now to work out how to pull the widgets information before viewPager2 turns to a new fragment.